# parsing output of $.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have

```
var x = $(data).html();
```

generating this html as value of x (i see this when i execute console.log(x)

```
 <td>
   070212
 </td>
 <td>
   NSG851006
 </td>
 <td>
   some dummy text
 </td>
 <td>
   ton
 </td>
 <td class="need_this">
   1,00
 </td>
 <td>
   0,00
 </td>
```

Can someone point me how to get value of "need_this" td (1,00) in a separate variable?

I tried `var y = $(x).attr(".need_this")` but got error "attr is not function"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `.html()` - that just produces a string of HTML, but your `$(data)` variable is already a representation of DOM elements that can be traversed using standard jQuery functions:

```
var y = $(data).find('.need_this').text();
```